# What does 'quiesce' stand for?

Tags: db2, db2-luw

I want to know what does "quiesce" in "db2 luw" means, how can I use it in linux and how it can affect the access to the tablespaces

I want to know how to tell whether or not a tablespace in a ddl was quiesced or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To Quiesce means to pause/alter an application/device to allow the application/device to achieve a consistent state.

In terms of DB2 the Quiesce command should force all the users off the specified database and should flush all the buffers to disk (been a while since I've used DB2).

While the database is a Quiesced mode there are users who can still access the database such as SYSADMIN and SYSMAINT.

There are several DB2 functions that can be used to determine the status of a table such [db2tbst](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/dm-0407melnyk/) and [MON_GET_TABLESPACE_QUIESCER](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.rtn.doc/doc/r0061349.html)

Answer (score 0):

Quiesce mean locking a database from creating of external connection through any applicaton, if we quiesce any database in db2 then we are restricting other application users to access that database, means a user cannot connect his/her application from that database and will not be able to fire any query on that database.

Also, All other connection from the database those are connected are released after quiesce.

Comment: "from creating any external connection through any application" - not exactly true. If you have QUIESCE CONNECT authority assigned to that ID, then it can connect, even if the database is quiesced. Although, in general, that is the intent of quiesce.